# Не работает скрипт на jQuery в блоге на WP

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Есть скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var coffeeCups = $("#entryContent").text().length / 1000;
$("#entryContent").append("<h3>Мы выпили " + coffeeCups + " чашек кофе, пока писали эту статью</h3>");
});
```

Проверила его на jsfiddle — работает.

Подключила к блогу на Wordpress через wp_enqueue_script(). Скрипт загружается в head, но не работает.

Вот пример поста в блоге: http://mnogo-smysla.ru/smysl-filma/smysl-filma-velikij-getsbi/. По логике h3 должен выводиться после блока рекомендуемых постов. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: замените знак `$` в скрипте на `jQuery`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ is not a function

поменяйте на старую версию вызов тоесть

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var coffeeCups = jQuery("#entryContent").text().length / 1000;
    jQuery("#entryContent").append("<h3>Мы выпили " + coffeeCups + " чашек кофе, пока писали эту статью</h3>");
});
```